# Using definition of limits and Clairaut's Theorem so as to calculate a partial derivative (steps verification)

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, solution-verification

For an infinitely differentiable function $f(x,t)$ and $a \in \mathbb{R}$ does the following hold?

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial{t}} \exp\left( \frac{\partial{f(x,a)}}{\partial{x}} \right) = \exp \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial{x}} \frac{\partial{f(x,a)}}{\partial{t}} \right)$$

Well, I have no proof, but I think it is since we can put the limit inside the argument of the exponential function and then use Clairaut's Theorem. Is it correct?

**EDIT**
Let me link with this one: [About Partial Derivatives of a function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3571837/about-partial-derivatives-of-a-function)

Comment: No! LHS is $0$ and RHS is $1$.

Comment: Did you mean $$\frac{\partial}{\partial{t}} \exp\left( \frac{\partial{f(x,t)}}{\partial{x}} \right)_{t=a} = \exp \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial{x}} \frac{\partial{f(x,t)}}{\partial{t}} \right)_{t=a}?$$ Even there, I think you're missing a chain rule application.

Comment: Exaclty, I was about to edit the question again. @AdrianKeister so, just use chain rule?

Comment: I think I would buy this equation: $$\frac{\partial}{\partial{t}}\,\exp\left( \frac{\partial{f(x,t)}}{\partial{x}} \right) = \left[\frac{\partial}{\partial{x}} \frac{\partial{f(x,t)}}{\partial{t}}\right]\exp \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\,f(x,t) \right).$$ Evaluating at $t=a$ is kind of irrelevant, really.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!